# Cannot send UDP datagrams to server even with port forwarding

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, udp, portforwarding

I have a client and server application in C++ where the server is designed to 'listen' on port 44888 for incoming packets using a UDP socket and output any messages received. The client is designed to open a UDP socket and send data to the server through the same port.

I have port forward my router to redirect packets sent to my public ip address and port 44888 to my machines LAN IP. When I run the server on my machine, and launch the client on the same machine, packets will not get through if sent through my public ip address, but they will if I use localhost as the address. Additionally, people on external networks cannot use the client to send packets either

I have tried listening on my machine with netcat for connections on port 44888 and people in external networks can send messages through netcat on that port, so i'm pretty sure i'm port forwarding correctly so i'm honestly not sure what the problem is. Any thoughts?

The code is very rudimentary, as follows:

Server

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
    socklen_t clientAddrLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    char buffer[1024];

    // Create a UDP socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening socket" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up the server address structure
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(44888);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // Bind the socket to the server address
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error binding socket" << std::endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "UDP server listening on port 44888..." << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        // Receive data from clients
        ssize_t bytesRead = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &clientAddrLen);
        if (bytesRead < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Error receiving data" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        // Print the received message
        buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
        std::cout << "Received message from " << inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port) << ": " << buffer << std::endl;
    }

    // Close the socket (unreachable in this example)
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Client

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    // Create a UDP socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening socket" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up the server address structure
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(44888);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("OMITTED"); // Server's IP address

    while (true) {
        // Input a message to send
        std::cout << "Enter a message to send (or type 'exit' to quit): ";
        std::string message;
        std::getline(std::cin, message);

        if (message == "exit") {
            break; // Exit the loop
        }

        // Send the message to the server
        ssize_t bytesSent = sendto(sockfd, message.c_str(), message.size(), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
        if (bytesSent < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Error sending data" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Message sent successfully" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // Close the socket
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

This image shows I should be receiving the packets on wireshark (red is omitted public ip address)

[image: Image of packet sniffinf results]

This image shows a machine on an external network using the client I made to send udp packets to my server
[image]

This image shows my port forwarding

[image]

Comment: Offhand, I don't see any problem with either code. So the problem has to be in your network routing. Have you tried using a packet sniffer on your LAN to make sure the router is sending packets to your machine?

Comment: Are you definitely forwarding UDP? Does your ISP definitely allow inbound UDP? Do the forwarding rules definitely punch through you router's firewall? Does your host's firewall allow UDP (on that port) from all sources?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll add a screenshot of the results to the original post, the blocked out colour is my public ip address, 192.168.0.195 is the correct LAN IP of my device, so I seem to be receiving the packets

Comment: @Useless I added a picture of the port forwarding. If it didn't allow inbound UDP I don't think the packet sniffing would of worked in my comment to Remy? The same answer to the firewall unless i'm mistaken?

Comment: What if you send datagram with netcat (in UDP mode) and receive with your server? And vice versa: send with your client and receive with netcat?

Comment: @dimich I am able to do both with netcat

Comment: I solved the issue, edited the main post to reflect it, thanks everyone who commented.

Comment: Please don't edit your questions to provide answers. Post actual answers instead, which you have now. I have rolled back the edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, turns out even though I had allowed the file to accept incoming connections in the firewall on my Mac it was still blocking them, after completely disabling it they now go through, so it was my machine rejecting packets and not the port forwarding or code.